# Codeigniter 4 API project error: Controller or its method is not found

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

When I use the API on my local web server (laragon - Apache) it works fine, but when I upload the same project to the cloud web server I get the error:

[image: 404 Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\user::index]

Error message appears on all resources.
I already clear the cache with `php spark cache:clear` command but the problem remains.

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use App\Models\AppModel;
use Exception;

class User extends ResourceController
{
    protected $modelName = 'App\Models\UserModel';
    protected $format    = 'json';

    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->access_app()) {
            $users = $this->model->findAll();
            return $this->respond($users);
        }
        return $this->failUnauthorized("No tiene acceso a la base de datos");
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
$routes->group('user', function ($routes) {
    $routes->get('/', 'user::index');
    $routes->get('(:segment)', 'user::show/$1');
    $routes->post('/', 'user::create');
    $routes->put('(:num)', 'user::update/$1');
    $routes->delete('(:num)', 'user::delete/$1');
});
```

I cleared the project cache with a spark command

Comment: Have you changed base_url in your cofig file in your cloud server??

Comment: In local environment such as windows it doesn't create issues and app runs smoothly. But when you deploy in linux it create issues as linux file is case sensitive. That's why should replace all user:: by User::  inside Route file

Comment: Thanks @ArifulIslam, the problem was the case sensitivity in linux, when I changed user:: to User:: it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the case sensitivity in linux, when I changed user:: to User:: it worked fine. Thanks @ArifulIslam

Comment: Feeling great to hear that. I knew that, as I have got this issue in linux server in past .